# Why would the IRS ask for birth certificates or even audit a small tax return?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, dependents, audit

My daughter and her boyfriend live together, and he is the sole earner in the home. They each have a kid plus 1 together. H&R Block told them that he didn't make enough to do his return and now the IRS wants birth certificates. I'm a retired accountant and I've never heard of such a thing! 
They live in a different city than me and their cars broke down otherwise I would have done this for them. This is bugging me.

Comment: Hi. It is not clear what you are asking and the title does not make sense. I assume "they" is the IRS. What does not make sense: 1040EZ cannot be used if the filer is claiming dependents.

Comment: Jen - The H&R Block anecdote is off on a tangent that may be making the question a bit unclear. Is that really the question, or are you asking why the IRS would like to see birth certificates?

Comment: To the vote-to-close members - if the question is edited down to ask why the IRS requires birth certs for a low income return, it might be a decent question, in light of the answer posted by Hart. Patience.

Comment: Are you just complaining here? The reality is that unless your friend supplies the examiner with birth certificates proving that he has children, then the IRS is going to deny your friend's attempt to claim child tax credits and assess additional taxes and penalties. If you are an accountant, you should know that anybody who claims a credit or deduction better be prepared to prove that they are entitled to that deduction.

Comment: @FiveBagger Maybe they retired before 1975. 

Comment: @Damila+ in fact 1040EZ and 1040A no longer exist at all, instead there is now an 'a la carte' approach where the 'basic' 1040 is roughly what 1040EZ used to be, and for anything more you have to add back in some or all of six numbered schedules (in addition to the traditional schedules A, B, C, D, F, SE etc) -- if you use paper. If you efile, as a large preparer like HRB will, it's all XML files anyway.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for that information! The original question mentioned asked about EZ  I assumed if he's already being audited that it was for the 2017 tax year. The question is more clear now. But this is good to know!

Comment: aaah...  The IRS wants Birth Certificated for the *children*. Not the couple ?

Answer (score 83):

For people that don't earn very much, the largest single financial event of the year is often getting a large tax refund thanks to the Earned Income Credit and the Child Tax Credit. These refundable credits can result in people getting refunds for thousands more than what they had withheld over the year. This makes fraudulently claiming dependents potentially lucrative. The IRS just wants documentation that supports what is being claimed on the tax return.

A birth certificate is a direct way to prove a child is yours, so it is not an uncommon document to provide.

Comment: The family configuration described also makes it possible that someone else has claimed one of the children listed on the return as a dependent.

Comment: @tbrookside Very true, there are many split couples that race to file claiming the dependents so the other parent can't. However, usually a birth certificate isn't going to resolve anything in those situations since without a legal agreement both parents have a right to claim the child even though only one of them can. It gets messy for sure.

Comment: From the [IRS Web Site](https://www.irs.gov/credits-deductions/individuals/earned-income-tax-credit/watch-out-for-these-common-eitc-errors): If we pick your EITC claim for an audit based on the child you claim, we ask for proof that the child is your qualifying child ... You need to send proof the child is related to you: ... Birth certificates or other official documents of birth that show you are related to the child,

Comment: @HartCO: In fact only one of them has the right and the law is clear who; the person who provided the majority of the person's support.

Comment: @Joshua That's true, I should have said that either of them could have the right to claim the child, the IRS has no idea which one. Some divorced parents alternate each year, some determine who will get the bigger benefit from claiming. In any case, birth certificate doesn't help with which parent should claim, but rather which people could have the right to claim the dependent.

Comment: @Joshua I believe the law actually states the one who is the higher earner, not the one who provides the most support.  In any event, it is clearly documented in the appropriate instructions of the 1040 and any deviation thereof requires an agreement and trust between the two parties.

Comment: @Paul - citation? This comment makes no sense to me.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer it seems I am wrong https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf read page 22-23.  What I noted only applies if the child lived equal nights with both parents.    Prior to that note, there is also a rule regarding if the child receives more than half of support from one of the parents.  Read all rules beginning page 20 and do the worksheet to see if the child is YOUR dependent.  This one of the few places that the tax code is very clear.